# Backbone Project works in all browsers apart from Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, backbone.js

I cannot get my BackboneJS project to work in Firefox. It works fine in Chrome, Opera and Safari. It is driving me crazy.

I have pulled all the unimportant stuff out of project and created a JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/LWUaH/

Code to satisfy the JSFiddle link...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    app = new window.AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Run the JSFiddle in Firefox and watch it die.

The errors are always in the jQuery file, different places and different errors for each version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From -> to:

```
$(content).html(new HomePageView().render().el);

$(this.content).html(new HomePageView().render().el);
```

Here you go, you weren't trying to select what you thought you were trying to!